# ddrescue: cloned partition to partition (different size)

Tags: partition, data-recovery, ddrescue

I tried cloning a WD Red 4TB drive to another 4TB Toshiba drive using ddrescue-gui. It failed since the target drive was 2KB smaller.

I then wiped the target disk, created a single partition of all the available space and then tried to recoved a single partition using the following command. However teh partition that I created was larger than the source partition.

```
ddrescue -v -d -f -r 2 -c 256 /dev/sdc4 /dev/sdb1 /home/ubuntu/Desktop/rescuelog/ddrescue-gui-part.log
```

1. Since I have cloned a smaller partition to a larger premade partition, will there be any issues with data or already written blocks from the older rescue? Would I need to edit the partition to make it the exact size?
2. The partition has 120320 Bytes of error. Should I run fsck on the target? Any command to retry ddrescue (Pls note that I'm cloning partition to partition; not to an image).

Comment: why?   the only reason to use ddrescue is if the drive is failing and you need to make a copy so you can recover what you can from it.  using ddrescue just to copy a partition (especially if copying to another partition of the same disk) makes no sense at all.  just use cp or rsync or tar or some other file-copying method.

Comment: rsync was failing due to bad blocks and I wanted a bit-true copy.

Answer (score 1):

1.1: No. ddrescue overwrites the target medium as necessary. There may be leftovers from previous writes, but they should not have any serious impact.

1.2: You may reduce the size of the partition to the size of the file-system. It is not necessary, though.

2.1: You already ran ddrescue with re-trimming. You can assume it did what it could. Re-running ddrescue with the same settings can help iff the source drive has some intermittent problems and is working some times better than other times (e.g. due to temperature changes).

2.2: Yes, you may run fsck on the copy. This is should be the last step to make the rescued file-system usable again.

Comment: Thanks. Feeling assured. So are the extra blocks in the partition not going to matter because the  cloned partition's superblock defines the partition / data boundaries? Fsck is at 8% after 5 hours now.

Comment: Yes. The file-system knows its own size. It is not derived from the partition (other than the usual "file-system should not be larger than the partition/device/container"). Good luck with the fsck outcome!